# What is the proper way to navigate to different components using regular buttons (instead of tabs)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

in my app I decided to use buttons in my menu instead of tabs, and I want to understand what is the proper way to do this navigation when each of the buttons lead to a different component.

So what I tried now is, MainComponent.html:

```
    <button md-button (click)="menuButtonClicked('component-one')">Button1</button>
      <button md-button (click)="menuButtonClicked('component-two')">Button2</button>

<h1>My App</h1>

  <div *ngIf="shouldDisplayComponent1">
    <component-one [someList]="list"></component-one>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="shouldDisplayComponent2">
    <component-two [someList]="list"></component-two>
  </div>
```

MainComponent.ts:

```
public shouldDisplayComponent1: boolean;
public shouldDisplayComponent2: boolean;

public menuButtonClicked(componentName: string) {
    switch (componentName) {
      case 'component-one':
         this.shouldDisplayComponent1 = true;
         this.shouldDisplayComponent2 = false;
      case 'component-two':
         this.shouldDisplayComponent2 = true;
         this.shouldDisplayComponent1 = false;
      default:
        throw('No such component')
    }
  }
```

Does that make sense? if not, please tell me what is the proper and elegant way to do that :)
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you use the `Routing` modules `<router-outlet>` usually

Here's the basic tutorial from Angular2's official routing guide:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', {'list': list}]" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  list: any  = ["my", "list"];
}
```

the `router-outlet` will become the component what `routerLink` is referencing to. The references are defined in the routing module

**Example routing module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Example on how to ge tthe route param (list inside the component:**

```
@Component({...})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){
    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params)=>{
       console.log(params['list']);
    });
  }
}
```

Full plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/2pTCEXSXF8GxpTySyQZE?p=preview

Routing tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: i saw that but didnt understand how I can pass a list to that component with routerLink, i need to pass this component a collection every time (the collection is changes from time to time so its a new collection)

Comment: @JohnBigs you can give the routerLink data in an array inside the html. And get that info from router.params inside the target component. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the click event of the button with a function in your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  onClick(){
    this.router.navigate(['/myRoute']);
  }
}
```

Or in your HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="/route">Route</a>
<button routerLink="/route">Route</button>
```